# Google Translation default Russian Language

Tags: angularjs, google-translate

I am using google translate widget for translating my website from English to Russian. How can I show translated webpage by default in russian language?

Answer (score 0):

ON translate.google.com/manager/website

on 2 step, in bottom, you can see

google translate can advice to translate into their native lang from browser request, not avtomatically translate!

or just use some hacks: see "Accept-Language" in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (ru) [NC]
RewriteRule .* yourserver.com [L]
```

then redirect to translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&sl=en&tl=ru&u=http://www.yourserver.com/